# retrieving data from database using java component on mule studio

Tags: java, database, mule, mule-studio

I have a requirement to pull the data from database using java component in mule studio.
That is Http>SOAP>Java Component(here in main class I will be giving the DB query to get details from my database)>SOAP>http
sending request in xml and getting response in xml.
I am getting a response when I use hardcoded values in java class ,but when trying to get from Database facing problems.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

below is the part of my java code

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "uname", "pwd");
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet result= st.executeQuery("select * from mule.tablename");

while(result.next())
{
    long quoteId  = result.getLong("quote_id");

    if(parameters.getQuote().getQuoteId() == quoteId)
    {
        QuoteResponseType quoteresp = new QuoteResponseType();
        quoteresp.supplierId = result.getString("supplier_id");
        quoteresp.respFreightAmount = result.getDouble("resp_freight_amount");
        quoteresp.respTaxAmount = result.getDouble("resp_tax_amount");
        quoteresp.supplierQuoteNumber = result.getString("supplier_quote_no");
        al.add(quoteresp);
    }

    NewQuoteResponse.quote.quoteResponse = al;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in your Mule flow and inject using `lookupConnector` in your Java implementation class as follows :-

```
<spring:beans>
<spring:bean id="DB_Source" name="DB_Source"class="org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource">
 <spring:property name="url" value="${url}"/>
 <spring:property name="driverName" value="${driverName}"/>
</spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
 <jdbc-ee:connector name="Database_Global" dataSource-ref="DB_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database">
     <jdbc-ee:query key="RetriveQuery" value="select * from mule.tablename"/>
 </jdbc-ee:connector>
```

And in your Java class you can get the access of your db component using `lookupConnector` :-

```
jdbcConnector = (JdbcConnector) muleContext.getRegistry()
                .lookupConnector("Database_Global");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you define a JDBC DataSource in your Mule xml file, and then inject it into your Java class.